# Populate dynamics CRM Activity Type sender from field using custom JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to populate the "From" look up field using custom JavaScript in Dynamics CRM.

I'm new to JavaScript and Dynamics really struggling to do this.

Below is a screenshot of my code and solution.

[image: The "From" field apparently this is Activity party type Sender]

```
function PopulateFromLookUpField(executionContext) {

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

var value = new Array(); //create a new object array
value[0] = new Object();
value[0].id = ; // set ID to ID
value[0].name = "new_name"; //set name to name
value[0].entityType = "sender"; //optional
formContext.getAttribute("sender").setValue(value);

}
```

I also tried the solution below it doesn't work.

```
function PopulateFromLookUpField(executionContext) {


 var lookUpObject.id = ;
   lookUpObject.name = "Joe CRM";
   lookUpObject.entityType = "sender";               
   formContext.getAttribute("sender").setValue(value);
   
}
```

Please advise and help.

Comment: please put the real entities you want to put, and the logical name of that field probably is "from", not "sender" but depends on where you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and this worked for me. Make sure to pass the correct field schema name, record GUID, record Name and entity Type properly.

```
var lookUpObject = new Array();
lookUpObject[0] = new Object();
lookUpObject[0].id = "7108f4e7-ac2b-eb11-a814-000d3a378f1b";
lookUpObject[0].name = "Arun Vinoth";
lookUpObject[0].entityType = "systemuser";               
formContext.getAttribute("from").setValue(lookUpObject);
```